# Crunchbang! how to install on second HDD and have working grub

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, crunchbang

I really want to try Crunchbang linux, but i have only ever used Wubi to dual boot and i have only even installed a Ubuntu based OS. is it as simple as just installing via a cd on the second hard drive, or do I have to partition do i have to set up grub menu or will the grub menu just detect the 2 operating system and give me the choice to boot between the 2 just like Wubi when installing Wubi? And will this effect my existing dual boot ubuntu partition?

this may not be very ubuntu related but after looking at various tutorials i just could nut understand, and people using ubuntu normally speak in a language i understand.

Comment: you should ask at http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/

Comment: Yes, you'll have to partition and deal with Grub settings.

Comment: i want to know if will effect my existing ubuntu partition on my first hard drive.

Comment: Wubi IS NOT true dual-boot, and does not use Grub as the bootloader (it uses Windows'). In theory you could do the same with Crunchbang, but you're on your own there!

Comment: This is off-topic, as per this meta discussion. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic. I suggest you try the chrunchbang forums, or our friends over at [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install crunchbang linux without affecting ubuntu , just insert live cd in the drive and follow the onscreen instructions . Keep in mind that crunchbang is highly unstable and it is not recommended for nomal users . If you just want to try crunchbang install it in virtualbox inside ubuntu

EDIIT

since crunchbang have no wubi like installer ,And you have no previous experiance with dualboot(wubi is not real dualboot) ,try it in virtualbox ,

If you have more doubts visit our neighbour unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am a longtime Crunchbang user. I agree with the virtualbox comment. The crunchbang iso also is a live cd. Have you tried that?

Comment: crunchbang is highly unstable, huh ?